# L-function and automorphisms of C

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory

Let $F$ be an element of the Selberg class and $\sigma$ a field automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $F=\sigma\circ F\circ\sigma^{-1}$. Is the following implication true?
$(x\in\mathbb{R}-\{1\}\Rightarrow F(x)\in\mathbb{R})\Rightarrow \sigma\in\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R})$
This is what I tried: suppose there's a real $x\neq 1$ such that $\sigma(x)=x$. Then for all non-negative integer $k$, $x_{k}:=F^{(k)}(x)$ is such that $\sigma(x_{k})=x_{k}$ where $F^{(k)}$ is the $k$-th iterate of $F$. So that, if $(x_{k})$ admits a limit $l$, $F(l)=l$. Suppose $\sigma(l)\neq l$. Then $F(\sigma(l))\neq \sigma\circ F(l)$, a contradiction. Hence $\sigma$ is continuous in a neighborhood of $l$ and thus $\sigma\in\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R})$. Is it correct?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT April 5th 2014: Assume, for the sake of simplicity, that $F=\zeta$ and $l>1$. As $\zeta$ is decreasing on $(1,+\infty)$, one gets $\sigma(l)=l$ rather easily. Hence $\sigma$ is continuous in a  neighborhood of $l$ (cause $\displaystyle{\lim_{k\to\infty}\sigma(x_{k})=\sigma(\lim_{k\to\infty} x_{k})}$). So that $\sigma$ is either the identity or the complex conjugation. Is this proof ok?